# Python error 2203 while installing on windows 7 64 bit service pack 1 and both 2.7.5 and 3.3.2

Tags: python

While running the python installer for any version I suddenly get an `error 2203` and it just doesn't want to run. It closes after I press ok.

I have been seeing weird things happening lately with python like it closing when `ctrl+z` is pressed. or even not indenting with the `tab` key. This started after I installed `ipython`. Any suggestions on how I may be able to resolve this?

Comment: If uninstalling ipython is an option, do it, then uninstall python too. Later reinstall ipython first.

Comment: Is this the same issue with the temp folder as [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2000547)? If so, try changing the permissions on the temp folder.